# Searching in string[,] using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two dimensional string array. I need to write LINQ query that match using first element but returns 2nd.

For example, for:

```
public string[,] values= { {"USA", "New York" }, { "Australia", "Sydney" } };
```

If in LINQ I match USA query should return "New York".

Please help

Comment: What if the data is `{ {"USA", ["New York", "Washington"] }, { "Australia", "Sydney" } };`

Comment: It will always be one value.

Comment: Then simply store data in Dictionary and find based on the key.

Comment: Ipsit: wouldn't it be a waste of processing power to put all elements in a dictionary if you only need the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
string state = Enumerable
    .Range(0, values.GetLength(0))
    .Where(i => values[i, 0] == countryName) // here country name is "USA"
    .Select(i => values[i, 1])
    .FirstOrDefault(); // returns New York.
```

Additionally, as per comments, you can use a Dictionary then you can simply use this:

```
state = values.ContainsKey("USA") ? values["USA"] : string.Empty;
```

Comment: Returning "not there" as a string when nothing is found is a very bad idea.